# Need a ruby solution for executing a method in separate process

Tags: ruby, process, asynchronous, eventmachine, workling

I am implementing a poller service whose interface looks like this.

```
poller = Poller.new(SomeClass)
poller.start
poller.stop
```

The `start` method is supposed to continuously start hitting an http request and update stuff in the database. Once `start`ed, the process is supposed to continue till it is explicitly `stop`ed.

I understand that implementation of `start` needs to spawn and run in a new process. I am not quite sure how to achieve that in Ruby. I want a ruby solution instead of a ruby framework specific solution (Not rails plugins or sinatra extensions. Just ruby gems). I am exploring eventmachine and starling-workling. I find eventmachine to be too huge to understand in short span and workling is a plugin and not a gem. So it is a pain get it working for Ruby application.

I need guidance on how do I achieve this. Any pointers? Code samples will help.

**Edit**

Eventmachine or starling-workling solution would be preferred over threading/forking.

Comment: Do you need a separate process or just a separate thread?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as I am able to run the poller as given above.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use the example from [`Process#kill`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Process/kill/class):

```
class Poller
  def initialize klass
    @klass = klass
  end

  def start
    @pid = fork do
      Signal.trap("HUP") { puts "Ouch!"; exit }
      instance = @klass.new
      # ... do some work ...
    end
  end

  def stop
    Process.kill("HUP", @pid)
    Process.wait
  end
end
```

Comment: A few questions.

1) What is the purpose of the code `Process.wait`?
2) Is forking safe in ruby. Asking because I have read/heard/learnt  that processes and threading in ruby are not so reliable. Can you please justify your solution?

Comment: 1) I guess that the child process is not terminated as soon as you call `kill`, there's a `trap` call which should do the cleanup in the child process and it could take some time. `wait` is there to wait for the very exit. 2) Define _safe_. Forking works as in any other language, it is feature of OS, not of a language.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Poller

    def start
       @thread = Thread.new { 
           #Your code here
       } 
    end


    def stop
       @thread.stop
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered out the [Daemons](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) gem?